# Magento backend - manage products - move qty field in the general tab

Tags: magento, backend, product, stock

I would like to know if there is a way in Magento (1.5) to move the qty field from backend catalog/manage products/inventory tab to catalog/manage products/general tab.

Thank you by advance.

Comment: This is not a good idea as the qty is related to other stock values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zard, the stock information is not exactly part of the Product, but from the ProductStock. So, you cannot reorder the fields using the Attribute Set Manager.

In order to do what you want, you are going to need to add some code (to hide the field in the inventory tab, and to show it in the general tab). If you keep the input's name, then the controller should just handle the data.